# Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: o. Path '', line 1, position 1

Tags: c#, json

I am using C# with Json.NET. JSON Object which I am passing

```
{ "user": { "name": "Bindu" } };
```

C# code in which I am handling this JSON object is:

```
public class user
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

}

public void SampleEvent(string param)
{
    List<user> s = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<user>>(param);
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Sample Event Called");
}
```

Using Newtonsoft.Json to deserialize the JSON object. In "param" I always get the JSON object only (like [object Object]).

But when I try to deserialize it I am always getting

> "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: o" exception.

Tried different scenarios but always facing the same issue. Also checked whether the JSON which I am passing is valid or not through this link http://jsonlint.com/. Its valid.

Please help on this. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON `{ "user": { "name": "Bindu" } }` is not a list of `user` but is more like:

```
public class SomeWrappingClass
{
    public user user { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to serialize it as a list then the format should be:

```
[{ "name": "Bindu" }]
```

---

Following works:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeWrappingClass>(
    "{ \"user\": { \"name\": \"Bindu\" } }");
```

Or for a collection of objects:

```
var data = "[{ \"user\": { \"name\": \"Bindu\" } }, { \"user\": { \"name\": \"Mohapatra\" } }]";
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SomeWrappingClass>>(data);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Changed the C# code as  SomeWrappingClass s = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeWrappingClass>(param);   Getting this error - Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'UCRS.MainWindow+SomeWrappingClass' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.                                                                                                  So changed it to list  - List<SomeWrappingClass> s = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SomeWrappingClass>>(param); Again facing the same issue.

Comment: @SwethaBindu - you are mixing things. For the described input in the question the following answer works - tested it. You are trying to deserialize an int array to the `SomeWrappingObject` - it won't work.

Comment: @SwethaBindu - if you try to deserialize `[1,2,3]` to something that it is not - then it will fail. if it is an `int[]` then that is what you should deserialize to.. But that is a follow-up and not the data from the question

Comment: var userlist = "[{ \"user\": { \"name\": \"Bindu\" } }, { \"user\": { \"name\": \"Mohapatra\" } }]"; - this is string its working fine. I can able to deserialize it.

        var userlist1 = [{ "user": { "name": "Bindu" } }, { "user": { "name": "Mohapatra" } }]; - but if it is object when try to deserialize List<SomeWrappingClass> s = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SomeWrappingClass>>(param);     Getting exception. Can you please provide some example. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your patience :). Yes it works because it is string  "[{ \"user\": { \"name\": \"Bindu\" } }, { \"user\": { \"name\": \"Mohapatra\" } }]";
Please try with this - var userlist1 = [{ "user": { "name": "Bindu" } }, { "user": { "name": "Mohapatra" } }];  I will get this object from web page I am handling it through Objectforscripting class in c#. Please pass object not string.Thanks

Comment: @SwethaBindu - you cannot hold a json in c# just like that. Read it from a file or get it from somewhere but having it just as is in the C# code will result in a compilation error.

Comment: I am getting this object from webpage when some action is happened on their page they are passing this [{ "user": { "name": "Bindu" } }, { "user": { "name": "Mohapatra" } }] . I am getting it as [object Object] JSON object. Some how I need to deserialize it in c# code using Newtonsoft.Json.

Comment: @SwethaBindu - what is  [object Object] JSON please show the code